# Set Format of Telerik Grid Filter Datepicker

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, datepicker, telerik, telerik-grid

I've used Telerik `DatePickers` throughout the project and when I select a date its in the desired format `dd/MM/yyyy`.

But, I have a Telerik `Grid` that has a date column. As a result the filter option allows the user to use a Telerik `DatePicker` to select a date to filter by. When I select a date its appearing in an American format i.e. MM/dd/yyyy (6/25/2020).

`AppDate` in my model is type `DateTime`.

I have tried the following to format the `DatePicker` value but it doesn't seem to work.

```
columns.Bound(o => o.AppDate)
        .Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
        .ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(AppointmentDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy') #");
```

How can I change this so that when I select a date it appears in the format dd/MM/yyyy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-column-datetime-filter-format

add a filter template that calls a js function to overwrite the existing template

```
columns.Bound(o => o.AppDate)
    .Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
    .ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(AppointmentDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy') #")
    .Filterable(x => x.UI("datePicker"));


function datePicker(args) {
    args.element.kendoDatePicker({
        format:"dd/MM/yyyy"
    });
}
```

There is another filter template type if you are using row filtering

```
.Filterable(x => x.Cell(y => y.Template("datePicker")));
```

Although... the globalization method in that thread is also a good idea. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/overview

Comment: element in args.element is undefined when I use Filterable

Comment: I took out the .element part and its working now! Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the below simple code in order to solve your problem.

- In this you make changes directly in the XML code.

```
<Telerik:GridDateTimeColumn 
      DataField="DateThatUserPicked" 
      DataType="System.DateTime"
      DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" 
      HeaderText="DateThatUserPicked" 
      SortExpression="DateThatUserPicked" 
      UniqueName="DateThatUserPicked"> 
</Telerik:GridDateTimeColumn>
```

- Or if it does not work for you use the `boundColumn` below:

```
<Telerik:GridBoundColumn 
      DataField="DateThatUserPicked" 
      DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" 
      DataType="System.DateTime" 
      HeaderText="DateThatUserPicked">
</Telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

Comment: This is for a newer version of Telerik that I currently do not have.

Comment: @BadDub , just take the new version and use my answer  , it is simple and easy